# adding multiple qslider and qspinner

Tags: c++, qt, loops, qslider, qspinbox

I add `QSlider` and `QSpinBox` with this code

```
QSpinBox *spinner2 = new QSpinBox;
QSlider *slider2   = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical);
spinner2->setRange(2,100);
slider2->setRange(2,100);
QObject::connect(spinner2, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), slider2, SLOT(setValue(int)));
QObject::connect(slider2, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), spinner2, SLOT(setValue(int)));
spinner2->setValue(10);

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(slider2);
layout->addWidget(spinner2);
```

I would like to add 30 of them, how can I do it by a loop?

Comment: What's your exact problem with using a loop? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do that in the following way:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;

// The main layout of the widget that will hold multiple spinner-slider pairs.
QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    QSpinBox *spinner2 = new QSpinBox(widget);
    QSlider *slider2   = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical, widget);
    spinner2->setRange(2, 100);
    slider2->setRange(2, 100);
    QObject::connect(spinner2, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), slider2, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    QObject::connect(slider2, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), spinner2, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    spinner2->setValue(10);

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(slider2);
    layout->addWidget(spinner2);

    mainLayout->addLayout(layout);
}

widget->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Qt signal mapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html) because that is exactly what it's designed to do.

The signal mapper class groups signals, and then reemits them based on an input integer, QString, or widget parameters.

I'll leave the signal mapping as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: The code above only connects a slider/spinbox pair to each other, no signal mapping needed so far.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP needed 30 unique slots for each of the spinboxes which would require a signal mapper.